# Does there exist such an upper bound for $g(n)$?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, solution-verification

If a function $g(n)$ satisfies $g(n)<n^5$ where $n$ is a positive real, does that mean there exists a real number $m,m<5$ such that $g(n)<n^{m}$

This isn’t from any particular question I was just wondering if this was possible, because my logic was that $g(n)$ never touches the line $n^5$, therefore, there should be a line $n^{m}$ between lines $g(n)$ and $n^5$

Comment: Hint:  Suppose $g(n)=n^5-10^{-10}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a function like $g(n)=n^5-10^{-10}$.  There is no $m<5$ such that $g(n)<n^m$ for all $n$.

To see that, suppose that we had such an $m$.  We can suppose $m>0$, since the claim is clear for $m≤0$.  Then we'd have $$10^{-10}>n^5-n^m=n^m\left(n^{5-m}-1\right)$$

for large $n$.  But $n^m\to \infty$ for large $n$ and $n^{5-m}-1>1$ since $5>m$, hence we have a contradiction.

Comment: What if you knew $g(n)$ didn’t have a constant term such as $-10^-10$ would there still be a contradiction?

Comment: The constant is not important.  Take $g(n)=\frac 12n^5$.  Still easy to see that there is no $m$ that works.

Answer (score 1):

No. For any $m<5$, with $g(n):=n^{(m+5)/2}$ you have

$$n^m<g(n)<n^5$$ so for any $m$ you will always find a $g$ that contradicts.

There is plenty of room between $n^m$ and $n^5$.

[image]

---

By the way, assume that $m=4.9$ was a solution, and $g(n)<n^5\implies g(n)<n^{4.9}$. But then, as $5$ has nothing special, why not $g(n)<n^{4.9}\implies g(n)<n^{4.8}$, also causing $g(n)<n^5\implies g(n)<n^{4.8}$ ? And what would stop the exponent from decreasing ?

Comment: The way I read the question:  "Assume that $g(n)<n^5$, for a particular function $g(n)$.  Can we then find a real number $m<5$ with $g(n)<n^m$?"  That is, I don't believe the OP was hoping for a "universal" $m$ that worked for all functions bounded by $n^5$.  Of course, I might have it wrong.

Comment: @lulu: my answer does not invoke a universal $m$. It shows that for any $m$ there is a contradicting $g$.